# Understanding Kubernetes pod resource utilization in GCP monitoring

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

let's say I have the following resource requests:

- cpu 25m
- mem 256Mi

And I have the following limits:

- cpu 1
- mem 1Gi

And I have the following utilization

- cpu 15.01%
- mem 17.24%

Question... Is utilization % of limits or % of requests?

My presumption is it would be % of limits. So then if I want my cpu at 75% utilization I would just have to scale it down which would get me to `200m` using the math below

```
(15.01%*1000)/0.75 = 200
```

[Update]

- I was looking at GCP in the monitoring section of GKE pods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are correct. `kubectl top pod` also presents the current usage in millicores, so it can also be used to calculate a possible limit reduction.

```
kubectl top pod  | grep prometheus-k8s | awk '{print $2}
405m
```

So I set my limit with.
(405 * 100) / 75 = 540m